# Dealing with 32bit overflow assembly x86 at&t

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-overflow, att

How to deal with overflow, if I can't work on 64 bit registers? it's the only condition. Here is sample of code:

```
.data
m:    .long 3386449920
base: .long 483778560,225763328,109240320,26664960,413385
```

In `start:` i have some multiplication and addition instructions

```
movl $0, %edi
movl m, %eax
movl base(,%edi,4), %ebx
imul %ebx, %eax
inc %edi
movl base(,%edi,4), %ebx
addl %ebx, %eax
```

Comment: Well I don't know, how do you want to deal with it?

Comment: Well i don't know too, that's why I'm asking. Maybe there is a solution to divide it to some parts and keep it in other registers(?)

Comment: There is, but then what do you want to happen? Do you want to multiply `m` by `base`?

Comment: I use it in RNS reverse conversion. In final result i have number which fit in 32bit register, but in the entire proccess i have few critical points when it doesnt, numbers have around 44bits length and working on 32bit registers  causes wrong calculations, bad results.

Comment: 1) Are you aware that the "imul" instruction performs an 8x8->16, 16x16->32 or (in your case) 32x32->64 bit multiplication, so the high 32 bits of the multiplication are in the "edx" register? 2) Do you know about the carry flag and the addition with carry (adc) instruction?

Comment: @MartinRosenau not here though, only the "1 explicit operand" version has the "wide result", this is just the regular 32x32->32 `imul`

Comment: I can't see anything in `%edx` register using `gdb`, just old stuff.

Comment: @1kka - I'm sorry. You use the "new" variant of the IMUL operation that has two arguments. This will in fact only do a 32x32->32 multiplication. The "old" variant with only one argument ("imul %ebx") will do a 32x32->64 multiplication: (Argument)x(%eax)->(%edx:%eax). Using this variant the meanings of the eax and edx registers are pre-defined - you cannot use other registers. Replace "imul %ebx, %eax" by "imul %ebx" and you'll have the high 32 of 64 bits in the edx register.

Comment: Shouldn't it be an unsigned `mul` btw?